# If the Infinity Stones can do anything, why could they not bring this dead character back?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

When

> Black Widow sacrifices herself

in *Avengers: Endgame*, it is said she cannot be brought back, because she was exchanged for the Soul Stone.

Yet Gamora, who was sacrificed for the Soul Stone came back, even though it was through time travel. Bruce explains that the time travel doesn't work like in other movies, you cannot change the present by changing the past. So should she stay dead?

Comment: "Dead" Gamora **didn't come back**. I think you are mistaken.

Comment: There is __[this interview](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/29/movies/avengers-endgame-questions-and-answers.html)__ with the writers Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely: ___The biggest question about it is what Thor raises there on the dock. “We have the Infinity Stones. Why don’t we just bring [Natasha] back?” But that’s the everlasting exchange. You bring her back, you lose the stone.___

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't bring back anyone who was sacrificed for the Soul stone in a particular timeline. The Gamora in *Endgame* was the one from 2014 that time travelled along with Thanos and Nebula.

Comment: I think the words used by Red Skull are that the Soul Stone requires an "everlasting sacrifice"

Comment: Could they not have grabbed a copy from earlier that day? As happened with Gamora

Comment: The timeline from which Gamora came from no longer exists after the stones were returned so no one is going to miss her. Natasha on the other hand does not exist after the point in time from where the Soul stone was retrieved so there is no copy to get. You cant get one from before the incident as the timeline will be altered.

Answer (score 7):

The process for earning the Soul Stone is irreversible. Returning the stone simply wouldn't bring the dead one back. The soul exchanged for this stone will be sealed in that place forever.

From [this interview](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/) with Joe Russo,

> Q: Can you get the soul your sacrificed for the Soul Stone back when you return it?
>
> A: No, the process is irreversible. Even if you have returned it to its original location, you wouldn’t be able to get the person back. In fact, it’s not really returning the Stone, more like put it back properly. **The tribute soul for the Soul Stone will forever be sealed in that place, therefore Black Widow is gone forever.**

Comment: But is it possible to create a completely new copy using the deathold and mindstone like wandavision and AOS?

Answer (score -5):

actually Steve Rogers returned the soul stone to the exact moment when it was removed from that moment in time undoing the everlasting sacrifice and returning Natasha from the dead

Comment: Wlcome to Movies.SE! Do you have any evidence to support that, like an interview with the directors, or is this just a theory you made up?

Comment: Except... nope. Not happening. See the interviews above that clearly and definitely state it doesn't work like that - Nat's dead, period.